# dynamically load row and column of an image gallery ionic grid

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, virtualscroll, ion-grid

I have an image array of 20 images. I want to dynamically load my images in a virtual scroll grid form whereby every row has 4 columns but not sure how to get it done

This is my current code

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid [virtualScroll]="photo_library">
      <ion-row *virtualItem="let photo" ng-if="$index % 4 === 0">
        <ion-col>
            <ion-img [src]="photo.avatarUrl"></ion-img>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-content>
```

But this generates a row and 1 column but I want dynamically to have 4 columns in one 1 row. How do i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid >
      <ion-row [virtualScroll]="photo_library" >
        <ion-col col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3 *virtualItem="let photo ">
            <ion-img [src]="photo.avatarUrl"></ion-img>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-content>
```